# Network sensoring with exceptionally large flows

Tags: networking, security, sensors, suricata

I wanted to know if anyone had experience handling single flows that generate 90 kpps or upward of traffic. My conundrum is that I use tools which I would like to be able to properly see an entire flow with (Zeek, Suricata), however both of these utilities are not capable of handling larger traffic volumes if a single connection exceeds a "worker thread's" maximum processing rate. Because a single connection is able to generate this volume of traffic, I am not aware of a load balancing method and accompanying software that would produce similar resulting information from Zeek & Suricata(Understandably this matters a lot less with Zeek, as seeing the entire connection isn't strictly necessary, however having a giant connection fill the rx ring results in losing subsequent connections)

I am hoping someone might have experience handling this type of situation or knows of software which has a less restrictive processing per "worker/thread" rate that would produce similar results(or honestly any results that aren't massive amounts of packet loss).

Comment: You might find a better audience for this question on one of SuperUser's sister sites on the Stack Exchange network, such as Server Fault or Network Engineering.

Comment: I'll try posting there also, thanks.